# Passing in dropdown options in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass options into my dropdown component. I have looked at some example online but they seem to show the list items imbedded into the dropdown itself. I am new to react so may not understand it properly but that approach would make it less reusable.

Here is my attempt at doing it.

main.jsx

```
var options = {
    dropdownOptions: [{
        value: 1, text: 'One', url: 'http://One.com'
    },{
        value: 2, text: 'Two', url: 'http://One.com'
    },{
        value: 3, text: 'Three', url: 'http://One.com'
    }]
}

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <div>
            <Dropdown title="Hello" />
        </div>
    }
});
```

dropdown.jsx

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var list = this.props.dropdownOptions.map(function(dropdownProps){
            return <li>{...dropdownProps}</li>
        });
        return <div className="dropdown">
            <button className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                {this.props.title}
                <span className="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                {list}
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
});
```

Comment: You seem to have the right idea. You just need to pass options as a prop into the dropdown in main.jsx

Comment: {...dropdownProps} will only work if you're using es6/7 and it also needs to be within the `<li {..dropdownProps}>` tag. Are you getting any errors? Code looks pretty solid on the whole

Answer (score 1):

Got it working thanks to the people who commented.

main.jsx

```
var React = require('react');

var Dropdown = require('./../components/dropdowns/dropdown');

var dropdownOptions = [{
        value: 1, text: 'One', url: 'http://One.com'
    },{
        value: 2, text: 'Two', url: 'http://One.com'
    }, {
        value: 3, text: 'Three', url: 'http://One.com'
}]


module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <div>
            <Dropdown title="Hello" dropdownOptions={dropdownOptions}/>
        </div>
    }
});
```

dropdown.jsx

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var list = this.props.dropdownOptions.map(function(dropdownProps, i){
            return <li {...dropdownProps} key={i}>{dropdownProps.text}</li>
        });
        return <div className="dropdown">
            <button className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                {this.props.title}
                <span className="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                {list}
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
});
```